# Reverse a string using two-pointer method in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse a string. I am aware of `.reverse` function and other methods in Js to do so, but i wanted to do it this two-pointer method.

The problem is the string is not getting updated. Is there anything i am not aware of strings. Whats wrong here ?

```js
function reverseString(s) {
  let lengthOfStr = 0;

  if ((s.length - 1) % 2 == 0) {
    lengthOfStr = (s.length - 1) / 2
  } else {
    lengthOfStr = ((s.length - 1) / 2) + 1;
  }
  let strLengthLast = s.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i <= lengthOfStr; i++) {
    let pt1 = s[i];
    let pt2 = s[strLengthLast];

    s[i] = pt2;
    s[strLengthLast] = pt1;
    console.log('----', s[i], s[strLengthLast]);
    strLengthLast--;
  }
  return s;
}
console.log(reverseString('hello'));
```

Comment: [String docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#character_access): "When using bracket notation for character access, attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties involved are neither writable nor configurable. (See `Object.defineProperty()` for more information.)"

Comment: Scripts are immutable in Javascript. You cannot mutate a readonly structure. It's not same as how you do it in C or C++ with pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike in C, strings in JavaScript are immutable, so you can't update them by indexing into them. Example:

```js
let s = 'abc';
s[1] = 'd';
console.log(s); // prints abc, not adc
```

You'd need to do something more long-winded in place of `s[i] = pt2;`, like `s = s.substring(0, i) + pt2 + s.substring(i + 1);`, and similarly for `s[strLengthLast] = pt1;` (or combine them into one expression with 3 calls to `substring`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesnt update the string, but if you handle the replacement as an array/list it works as follows:

```
function reverseString(s) {
  let lengthOfStr = 0;
  sSplit = s.split("");

  if ((s.length - 1) % 2 === 0) {
    lengthOfStr = (s.length - 1) / 2
  }
  else {
    lengthOfStr = ((s.length - 1) / 2) + 1;
  }
  let strLengthLast = s.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i <= lengthOfStr; i++) {
    let pt1 = sSplit[i];
    let pt2 = sSplit[strLengthLast];

    sSplit[i] = pt2;
    sSplit[strLengthLast] = pt1;
    console.log('----', sSplit[i], sSplit[strLengthLast],sSplit);
    strLengthLast--;
  }
  return sSplit.join("");
}
console.log(reverseString('Hello'));
```

returns: Hello => olleH

Comment: Because strings in JavaScript are immutable: they can't be updated. This is a great idea why [`"use strict";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) should be used: if you do, you get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'hello'`.

Comment: noted to the new knowledgebook. These are the things I just know how to do without knowing the whys XD Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As covered in comment, answers and documentation, strings are immutable in JavaScript.

The ability to apparently assign a property value to a primitive string value results from early JavaScript engine design that temporarily created a String object from primitive strings when calling a `String.prototype` method on the primitive. While assigning a property to the temporary object didn't error, it was useless since the object was discarded between calling the String method and resuming execution of user code.

The good news is that this has been fixed. Putting

```
 "use strict";
```

at the beginning of a JavaScript file or function body causes the compiler to generate a syntax error that primitive string "properties" are read-only.

There are many ways of writing a function to reverse strings without calling `String.prototype.reverse`. Here's another example

```js
function strReverse(str) {
    "use strict";
     let rev = [];
     for( let i = str.length; i--;) {
         rev.push(str[i]);
     }
     return rev.join('');
}

console.log( strReverse("Yellow") );
console.log( strReverse("").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that way, hopefully might be helpful for someone.

```
        const input = 'hello';  /*input data*/
        const inputArray = [...input];  /*convert input data to char array*/
        
        function reverseString(inputArray) {
        
           let i  = 0;
           let j = inputArray.length -1 ;
        
           while(i < j ) {
        
               const temp  = inputArray[i];
               inputArray[i] = inputArray[j];
               inputArray[j] = temp;
                
               i++;
               j--;
           }
        };
        reverseString(inputArray);
        console.log(inputArray)

      const finalResult = inputArray.join("");
      console.log(finalResult);
```

Thanks.